# How do I check what is being repeated in the array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to know what is being repeated in an array, and I am not sure what method to use to do so. `[1,2,6,8,8,8,2]`. I need it to print `8 occurs 3 times` `2 occurs 2 times`. How would I do this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberarray.count; i++){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let numbers = [1,2,6,8,8,8,2]
let cs = NSCountedSet(array: numbers)

cs.forEach { if cs.countForObject($0) > 1 { print("number: \($0) has an occurance of \(cs.countForObject($0))") } }
```

Something like this?

Output:

```
number: 2 has an occurance of 2
number: 8 has an occurance of 3
```